# Build string by generating random characters step by step

Tags: javascript, strings, node.js

I'm trying to create a program that will try to build a target string character by character by generating random characters. I have come up with the following Nodejs program with a little bit of Google help:

```
const args = process.argv.slice(2)

const targetWord = args[0]
let builtWord = ''

function getRandomChar() {
    return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (126 - 32 + 1)) + 32)
}

function updateWord() {
    const {length} = builtWord
    const nextChar = getRandomChar()
    process.stdout.write('\r')
    process.stdout.write(builtWord)
    process.stdout.write(nextChar)
    if (targetWord[length] === nextChar) {
        builtWord += nextChar
    }
}

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

async function main() {
    while (true) {
        updateWord()
        if (builtWord === targetWord) {
            break
        }
        await sleep(1000 / 16)
    }
}

main()
```

What are your thoughts on it, anything I can improve or do differently? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Extract magic numbers into constants

- For instance, what do `126` and `32` represent in the following line?

  ```
  return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (126 - 32 + 1)) + 32)
  ```

  It is much better to extract [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) into constants, i.e. to annotate them with a semantically meaningful name:

  ```
  const HIGHEST_ASCII_PRINTABLE_CHARACTER = 126;
  const LOWEST_ASCII_PRINTABLE_CHARACTER = 32;
  ```

  But even when you replace the numbers by their constant's name, it isn't immediately clear what you're doing with `-32`, `+32`, `Math.random()` and `Math.floor()` there. Even if you are accustomed to random number generation, a dedicated function call is more readable with less redundancy and in fact is easier to reason about:

  ```
  return String.fromCharCode(getRandomInt(LOWEST_ASCII_PRINTABLE_CHARACTER, HIGHEST_ASCII_PRINTABLE_CHARACTER));
  ```

  Especially, with your old code, I had to look up [Math.random() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/math.random) to make really sure that is produces a uniform distribution. Now you can just add a docblock comment to `getRandomInt` indicating that property.
- `await sleep(1000 / 16)` also features magic numbers.

### Miscellaneous remarks

- Using async-await for waiting after each loop iteration is a good use case and really makes the code cleaner!
- Extracting only a single property with the object destructuring syntax (`const {length} = builtWord`) seems a bit unidiomatic to me as opposed to `const length = builtWord.length`.
  Apart from that, you are using `length` only once anyway, so I would drop that variable all together.
- Try to avoid global variables and interdependencies.

  - For example, `builtWord` as well as `targetWord` are shared (and the former even modified!) by `main` and `updateWord`. I would suggest making `updateWord` accepting both as arguments and returning the possibly newly built word:

    ```
    function tryUpdateWord(currentBuiltWord, targetWord) {
        // This is a good moment to introduce a sanity check as well
        if (currentBuildWord.length >= targetWord.length) {
          throw new Error('<todo>');
        }

        const nextChar = getRandomChar()
        process.stdout.write('\r')
        process.stdout.write(currentBuiltWord)
        process.stdout.write(nextChar)
        if (targetWord[currentBuildWord.length] === nextChar) {
            return currentBuiltWord + nextChar
        }
        else {
            return currentBuiltWord;
        }
    }
    ```
  - Since the interdependencies have now been eliminiated, I would also move the part reading the process arguments into `main()`:

    ```
    async function main() {
        const targetWord = process.args[2]
        let builtWord = ''

        const SLEEP_PER_ITERATION = 1000 / 16;
        while (true) {
            builtWord = tryUpdateWord(builtWord, targetWord)
            if (builtWord === targetWord) {
                break
            }
            await sleep(SLEEP_PER_ITERATION)
        }
    }
    ```